# Importing local modules that are dot referenced with PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python script I'm working on that I am packaging into a one file executable with pyinstaller.

Within the script, when it is uncompiled, I am referencing a set of tools that live in a folder next to the main script, so something like this:

```
\parent
    ----->\tools\
       ------>db.py
       ------>file_utils.py
main.py
```

I've omitted the init, but it's there as well.  Within my script, I'm importing these files like

```
import tools.db
import tools.file_utils
```

and all of this works fine.  When I package it as an executable with PyInstaller, I am getting a module not found error for tools.  I've tried adding the absolute path to tools, adding tools and the relevant files to hidden imports, and all of this, but I have a feeling it's the way I'm calling them in the script.

I suppose all those helper scripts could just be in the parent directory next to the script, or I could add tools to the sys.path and just import db and fileutils directly, but that seems a bit janky and/or cluttered.  Anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from tools import db
from tools import file_utils
```

Comment: So that's what I had originally.  I replaced it with the dot notation, and nothing seemed to change.  I'm writing everything to a compile folder, so my pathex in my spec file is just to that compile folder, so I wonder if adding in the parent directory, or the tools directory, will help.  Going to try and recompile and see results.

Answer (score 2):

So, after flattening the entirety of my directory structure in a tmp folder to write the executable, and changing my spec file to not compile to a different directory (as well as adding the parent directory to the -p switch) and remembering to delete a reference in a different py file to another module that no longer exists, I got this all working.

I think I'll piece back the parts so I can make this work much easier in the future and try and identify which part of the process was giving my packaging ImportErrors, but it was a useful exercise in picking apart the pieces of PyInstaller a bit and learning more about hooks and imports and module/package level imports.

Comment: This was posted on 2015, since it's now 2019, have you found any new solution for this?

Comment: Mar 15 in this case was March 15th, 2019.  Ultimately, I ended up creating a new project directory, creating a venv, and calling pyinstaller from there.  I think there must have been something that was cached that was disallowing me to use pyinstaller.  The import statements I've marked as the accepted answer worked.  I don't remember all the specifics of the problem and solution, however.